# Restrict a user from accessing everything but a folder

Tags: linux, permissions, centos

I have a VPS running on CentOS 6. The parts inside the VPS are spread in different folders. My websites are in `/var/www/html` and some other key parts for my VPS are in `/home/`.

Could someone give me a quick guide on how to create a new user that would only be able to access the `/home/` directory and nothing else?

I tried searching around Google, but I guess I didn't know to phrase the questions...

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to achieve what you've requested just with privileges, but please read entire answer first and then decide what you want to do. (And please note that this doesn't include the "*nothing else*" part, some system files are accessible for everybody by default.)

1. Create a group that will be allowed to access `/home`:

   ```
   $ addgroup homeaccess
   ```
2. Create a new user account that will be privileged to access `/home`: (skip this step if you already have that user account set up)

   ```
   $ adduser --no-create-home HomeUser
   ```
3. Add yourself and that account to the group:

   ```
   $ adduser MyUsername homeaccess
   $ adduser HomeUser homeaccess
   ```
4. Make the group you've created an owner of `/home`:

   ```
   $ chgrp homeaccess /home
   ```
5. Let the group read, write and execute contents:

   ```
   $ chmod g+rwx /home
   ```
6. Optionally, do the same for subfolders/files:

   ```
   $ chgrp homeaccess /home/*
   $ chmod g+rwx /home/*
   ```

But **before you start doing that**, you should rethink your directory layout. `/home` is dedicated for user home directories and if you need to let another user access *entire* `/home`, then it's very likely that you're doing something wrong. If you have anything more than user directories in your `/home`, then your directory layout isn't good. Maybe simply creating another user and dumping all those files into his directory (`/home/user`) will be the best solution, because you'll both have directory structure fixed and another used with access to those files created. Creating a new user account along with his user directory is pretty simple:

```
$ adduser SomeUsername
```